# 2D top-down point and click movement and rotation in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, controls, 2d, mouseevent

I'm working on point and click car movement but I could did movement only hold click to car. I want to move the car when i click any point. I wrote this code. Also is it possible smoothly rotation? because there is skidmark of car and when i turning the car, it suddenly turning can you help me?

```cs
void Update()
{
    mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
    marker.position = mousePosition;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        moveToPosition = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        moveToPosition = false;
        SoundManagerScript.stopCarAudioSource.Play();
        SoundManagerScript.loopEngineAudioSource.Stop();
    }

    if (moveToPosition)
    {
        direction = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - transform.position.x, mousePosition.y - transform.position.y);
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mousePosition) < 100f)
        {
            moveToPosition = false;
        }
        transform.up = direction * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you've only got code going into the `OnMouseDrag` function and you're using `Vector.Lerp` incorrectly. Look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) but long story short, lerp needs to be constantly updated either via `Update` or a `IEnumerable`.

To give a very simple example, I would suggest trying something like this;

```
//get your click to register to this function
void OnMouseClick()
{
    moveToPosition = true;
    mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
}

void Update()
{
    if(moveToPosition)
    {
        increase += Time.deltaTime;
        direction = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - transform.position.x, mousePosition.y - transform.position.y);
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed);
        Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, direction, step, 0.0F);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mousePosition) < 5f)
        {
            moveToPosition = false;
        }

    }
}
```

It is untested but is basic enough to get you going on seeing something move.

Comment: giving this error: No overload for method `Distance' takes `3' arguments

Comment: @freedom667 Oops! Fixed now

Comment: but I have to move with OnMouseDrag too. this is only click. Also it's working when click to object. So your code is almostly same with my code. I want to click space

Comment: How are you calling OnMouseDrag? You need to make you have a collider on your object.

Comment: just like in my code. the object has collider already. Actually we have to change transform.position in Vector2.Lerp. when we change it with space. I think it will work

Comment: Sorry. your code working when i click to object, not space. I want point and move. well it have tow work with OnMouseDrag too.

Comment: I made it but. How can i smoothly rotation?

Comment: I fixed the quesstion

Comment: I have provided a basic way of adding smooth rotation in my answer.

Comment: rotation changing only x and y. y being 90 and x always changing. the car disappearing because of y